# How to implement string(xml) to memorystream to file in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string(xml) and I need to store it temporarily as memory stream and then store it as file at the end.

I know we can directly store xml in a file using textwriter but that is not what I want. I want the string to be converted to memory stream and then write into filestream.

how can I implement this? Sharing the code will be very helpful.

Comment: You could load the string with System.Linq.XDocument, do whatever you need to the xml, then call XDocument's Save() to save to file.

Comment: @Mark Byers, Thanks for your time. Well! I have cant say everything because of NDA. We have received few dlls from third party vendor. One of the method accepts memory stream as input, processes it & gives us another memory stream as output. I want to pass it a xml string and store the processed memory stream in a file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I get you, you want to open memory stream on a char array (string) that represents XML?

```
string xml;

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xml));

ms.DuStuf();

fileStream.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, xml.Length);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using .NET 4, this is very easy - you can just use [Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932(VS.100).aspx) to copy your MemoryStream into a FileStream directly.

If you're using an older version, you'll need to implement this yourself.  This tends to look like:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int read;
while ((read = source.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0) 
{
    destination.Write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```